# How to find the last occurence of a document based on another document's field in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

Let's have some test data first:

```
db.events.insertMany([
{
    datetime: ISODate("2017-01-01 00:00:00"),
    results: [
        { id: 2, note: "SK4 on alarm" },
        { id: 5, note: "UT7 on alarm" }
    ]
},
{
    datetime: ISODate("2017-01-01 00:15:00"),
    results: [
        { id: 2, note: "SK4 on alarm" },
        { id: 5, note: "UT7 on alarm" }
    ]
},
{
    datetime: ISODate("2017-01-01 00:30:00"),
    results: [
        { id: 5, note: "UT7 on alarm" }
    ]
},
{
    datetime: ISODate("2017-01-01 00:45:00"),
    results: []
},
{
    datetime: ISODate("2017-01-01 01:00:00"),
    results: [
        { id: 5, note: "UT7 on alarm" }
    ]
},
{
    datetime: ISODate("2017-01-01 01:15:00"),
    results: []
},
]);
```

I'd like to create a Gantt diagram for the events described above. My Gantt diagram needs two things:

- The title of an entry
- Start and end date of an entry

So from the above test data I need to generate an output like this:

```
[
    { 
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 00:00:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 00:30:00",
        "title": "SK4 on alarm"
    },
    {
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 00:00:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 00:45:00",
        "title": "UT7 on alarm"
    },
    {
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 01:00:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 01:15:00",
        "title": "UT7 on alarm"
    }
]
```

As you can see I need to get a list of ongoing alarms with a start date of when they appeared first and with an end date of when they disappeared.
Each alarm may appear more than once in the history, just like "UT7 on alarm" did.

I need to form such a mongodb query that returns the same output as written above.

I may have the theory in mind but cannot translate it to actual mongo query.
So to determine the end date of each event I would need to write a query that finds the document with the smallest datetime after a specific date (the event's `datetime`) where a given `id` is not present in the `results` array. **This is the step I don't know how to do.**

After this query I would have something like this:

```
[
    { 
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 00:00:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 00:30:00",
        "title": "SK4 on alarm"
    },
    {
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 00:00:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 00:45:00",
        "title": "UT7 on alarm"
    },
    { 
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 00:15:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 00:30:00",
        "title": "SK4 on alarm"
    },
    {
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 00:15:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 00:45:00",
        "title": "UT7 on alarm"
    },
    {
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 00:30:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 00:45:00",
        "title": "UT7 on alarm"
    },
    {
        "starttime": "2017-01-01 01:00:00",
        "endtime": "2017-01-01 01:15:00",
        "title": "UT7 on alarm"
    }
]
```

After this step I would need to filter out the duplicate entries. To do that my idea is to group the items by `"title, endtime"` and get the minimum `starttime`. That would give me the correct result, I suppose.

It's not a homework.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where does the data come from? Can you change the input schema? Could you e.g. write a "alarm starting" entry and an "alarm over" entry?

Comment: Good question! 
No, I can't change the input schema. They are stored in a way like a snapshot. Each document represents the full state of the application.

Comment: The alarm IDs... Are they a distinct set of integers that you can predict and control as in "know upfront" or "hard code"?

Comment: I don't really understand what "know upfront" and "hard code" mean in your context but yes, each alarm has its unique ID, so that would be the connection point when calculating the end date.

Comment: What I mean is do you know that you have e.g. alarms 1-5 but not 6 and could we hard code 1-5 then in the resulting query?

Comment: I see. No, I can't predict what id's I will get because they are auto-generated so any new kind of alarm will have the next available id.

Comment: Just to make me really understand this... Is the alarm ID like a sensor ID or an event ID? So if UT7 had another alarm sequence would it also show up with ID 5 or would it have a new ID.

Comment: It's like a sensor ID. You can see it in the example documents that UT7 alarm showed up twice with the same ID.

Comment: Riiight. True. ;) I sort of remember that. ;)

Comment: Can we assume a fixed interval? As in a precise 15 minutes between each measurement?

Comment: No we can't assume that too.

Comment: Man, you're doomed... That's a nasty bugger. How about solving it on the application layer instead?

Comment: That's plan B but for that I'd like to have a query that is as close to the final solution as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, I risked my relationship because of your question! It took me literally hours to come up with the following query which - luckily - produces precisely what you want.

Frankly, I hope it serves as a starting point for smarter people to come up with something leaner. I went in all directions but that's the only way I could make that thing work.

```
collection.aggregate({
    // first unwind to get one document per event
    $unwind: {
        path: "$results",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true // we need this in order to keep the dates for the empty ("no results") events
    }
}, {
    // we start building up some lookup data structure which we will need later
    $group: {
        "_id": "$datetime",  // for every date...
        "allResultIds": { $addToSet: "$results.id" }, // ...we want to capture the event ids and exclude duplicates
        "docs": { $push: "$$ROOT" } // ...and keep track of all documents we encounter
    }
}, {
    // we got to make sure that our events are nicely sorted to allow our following stages to work properly
    $sort: { "_id": 1 } // order by datetime
}, {
    // now, we produce the final lookup structure to help us later
    $group: {
        "_id": null, // we do not really want to group but instead group all documents into one
        "magicLookup": {
            $push: { "datetime": "$_id", "allResultIds": "$allResultIds" } // here is where we put the final lookup structure together
        },
        "docs": {
            $push: "$$ROOT.docs" // as always, we want to keep track of all documents
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs" // flatten result
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs" // flatten result again ;)
}, {
    $project: // restore original document structure but this time with the lookup included in every document
    {
        "magicLookup": 1,
        "_id": "$docs._id", // this is not even needed
        "datetime": "$docs.datetime",
        "results": "$docs.results",
    }
}, {
    // let's filter out documents with no results
    $match: {
        "results": { $exists: true }
    }
}, {
    // now, we can find the end date for all our events using the logic you described (first event after the current one without the same result id)
    $project: {
        "datetime": 1, // we want to keep the datetime information
        "results": 1, // the same for the results
        "endtime": {
            $min: { // find the minimum - luckily, this seems to work
                $filter: { // exclude all events for the result id we are looking at just now
                    input: {
                        $slice: [ // look at the documents *after* the current one - this is why we need the sorting stage before
                            "$magicLookup", // from the magic lookup
                            { $add: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$magicLookup.datetime", "$datetime" ] }, 1 ] }, // we want everything *after* the current event
                            { $size: "$magicLookup" } // up to a maximum of, well, err, the array length - whatever. This could be a hardcoded number or written more beautifully but I couldn't be bothered
                        ]
                    },
                    cond: {
                        $not: {
                            $in: [
                                "$results.id", "$$this.allResultIds"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
, {
    // (almost) lastly, we apply a little trick
    $group:
    {
        "_id": { "note": "$results.note", endtime: "$endtime.datetime" },
        "starttime": { $min: "$datetime" } // the smallest of all our event dates with the same same end date is our start date
    }
}, {
    // let's beautify the output a little
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "starttime": "$starttime",
        "endtime": "$_id.endtime",
        "note": "$_id.note",
    }
}
)
```

Comment: That's just WOW! Let me understand your well documented query first :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I accepted your answer! Thank you so much!
It inspired me a lot so that I could come up with my own solution too. Check it out :)

Comment: Haha. It's 1-0 for you. My solution has a bug, but yours works fine for the following case: lets say we have a date interval where an alarm was firing the entire time. Your solution returns the following document: `{"starttime": "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000Z", "note": "Some alarm note" }` without and `enddate` field, which means it didn't end in the time period. My solution does not return anything for that alarm.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that's not the final score. Keep playing!

Answer (score 1):

So, according to dnickless's answer, which is totally great!, I came up with this solution. It's almost the same length, except I didn't use `$filter, $$ROOT, $slice and $addToSet` which I'm not really familiar with.

```
db.events.aggregate([
    // Make sure everything is in historical order
    { 
        $sort: { datetime: 1 } 
    },
    // Build such a document where $left stores the original documents and $right stores only the event IDs seen at a given time
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            left: { $push: { datetime: "$datetime", events: "$results" } },
            right: { $push: { datetime: "$datetime", events: "$results.id" } }
        }
    },
    // Flatten by $left so each original document will have all the other documents (this is now like a SQL join)
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$left",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }        
    },
    // Flatten by $left.events so that each occured event has its own document tree
    {
        $unwind: "$left.events"
    },
    // Flatten by $right too so that we have a descartes product of each occured event (this is needed for the following filtering)
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$right",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    // Calculate fields for filtering: $dategt means if the $right event occured later in time than $left event
    // and $alarmoff means if $left event no longer present in the time when $right is stored
    {
        $project: {
            left: 1,
            right: 1,
            dategt: { $gt: [ "$right.datetime", "$left.datetime" ] },
            alarmoff: { $not: { $in: [ "$left.events.id", "$right.events" ] } }
        }
    },
    // Filter our irrelevant documents
    {
        $match: {
            dategt: { $eq: true },
            alarmoff: { $eq: true }
        }
    },
    // Let's put the documents back together so that each event occured in $left will have the minimum date from $right in which the $left event disappeared
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "datetime": "$left.datetime",
                "id": "$left.events.id",
                "note": "$left.events.note"                
            },
            "right": { $min: "$right.datetime" }
        }
    },
    // We have descending order, so we need to sort again for another grouping
    {
        $sort: {
            "_id.datetime": 1,
            "right": 1            
        }
    },
    // Need to group the documents again but now get the minimum start time of $left for each end time of $right
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                endtime: "$right",
                id: "$_id.id",
                note: "$_id.note"
            },
            starttime: { $min: "$_id.datetime" }
        }
    },
    // Let's beautify the output a little
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            starttime: 1,
            endtime: "$_id.endtime",
            note: "$_id.note",
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Frankly, that is too much for me to understand on a Monday but I'm amazed that you managed to rewrite that nasty bugger I created. ;) I'm glad I could help a little and thanks for the points. What would be interesting is to see the performance comparison between the two versions once you run them against a large production data set.

Comment: Actually the test data I gave is a quite small excerpt of the actual data I need to run this query against. Unfortunately, I cannot run our queries off the shelf on the large data set so I have to extend / rewrite it first. Once I'm comfortable with the final solution I'll try to measure performance.